# inserting and retrieving image in sql server using restful API

Tags: mysql, image, rest, jsp, blob

I am using mysql database and I want to store image in blob format.
I want to create a jsp form to accept image and other information in text format for uploading the post (like title, description). From jsp page I want to call rest web service to pass the image to database and retrieve it back. 
I am new with restful and I have no clue how to go along this.
Please help me!!
plz provide example if possible

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can track your image in sql server.

1.Serialize the image to a binary format so that it can be stored in a sql BLOB column, you can always pass the binary as json to your restful Api.
2. Save the path of the image in a varchar column so that you can load from it's physical path.

In your case you need to use first way.

probably this will help http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25280

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('image_field');
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  var description= $("input#description").val();
    formData.append('description', description);
       $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/echo",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
         processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if(response) {
            alert(response);
          } 
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error: ' , errorThrown);
       }
      });
      
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="image_field"><br><br><br>
<input type="text" id="description"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

You can use ajax calls to achieve this. I hope this will help you.